# C++ ifstream Reading groups of lines

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to get my ifstream to read multiple lines of text and start over again once it reaches a certain character.

For example, `myfile.txt` has this in it:

`300
200
10
10
/
200
300
20
20`

I want to use my method `LoadImg` for everyone 4 lines, the values in those lines being the parameters. I'm not exactly sure how many blocks of 4 lines there will be, but each will be separated with a `/`.

I'm kind of new to C++ btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
int i[4];
while (ifs >> i[0] >> i[1] >> i[2] >> i[3]) {
  // do some staff here with i[]

  ifs.get();  // get the trailing newline character '\n'
  if (ifs.peek() == '/')  // check the next character, because the last group has no '\'
    ifs.get();
}
```